# ChakraUI (react): How to disable all keyboard based navigation except for in inputs and textareas

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, chakra-ui

This can be done with either a Chackra theme, or simply being done directly on the window using react `useEffect`

I am trying to disable all NAVIGATION based on keypresses, including TAB, SPACE, and ENTER.

However, I want these keys to work normally in any input element or textarea element. I also want to be able to listen for these keys on the window and implement custom behaviour.

It would also be good if the ChakraUI `<NumberInput />` component would also work normally.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Similar problem but I'd like to override arrow navigation in modals. Arrows should navigate between modal items, not close button etc.